# allow open access to S3 bucket with certain restrictions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How do I set permissions in such a way that anyone can upload files to my bucket?

Here is an example that has these 3 features:

1. I can upload any file and download my file from anywhere.
2. But I am not able to download files uploaded by others.
3. However, I can delete files uploaded by others.

I will like to know how this bucket (abc) was set up and who owns it.

**1) I can upload:**

```
[root@localhost ~]# aws s3 cp test.txt s3://abc/
upload: ./test.txt to s3://abc/test.txt
```

**2) I can list contents:**

```
[root@localhost ~]# aws s3 ls s3://abc | head
                           PRE doubleverify-iqm/
                           PRE folder400/
                           PRE ngcsc/
                           PRE out/
                           PRE pd/
                           PRE pit/
                           PRE soap1/
                           PRE some-subdir/
                           PRE swoo/
2018-06-15 12:06:27       2351 0Sw5xyknAcVaqShdROBSfCfa7sdA27WbFMm4QNdUHWqf2vymo5.json
```

**3) I can download my file from anywhere:**

```
[root@localhost ~]# aws s3 cp s3://abc/test.txt .
download: s3://abc/test.txt to ./test.txt
```

**4) But not able to download other's file**

```
[root@localhost ~]# aws s3 cp s3://abc/zQhAqmwIUfIeDnEEHpiaGhXuERgO3bR84jkjhbei1aLiV1758t.json .
fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

**5) however, I can delete the file not uploaded by me:**

```
[root@localhost ~]# aws s3 rm s3://abc/zQhAqmwIUfIeDnEEHpiaGhXuERgO3bR84jkjhbei1aLiV1758t.json
delete: s3://abc/zQhAqmwIUfIeDnEEHpiaGhXuERgO3bR84jkjhbei1aLiV1758t.json
```

I am not sure how to set-up such a bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not advisable to setup a bucket in this manner.

The fact that *anyone* can upload to the bucket means that somebody could store, potentially, TBs of data and ***you* would be liable for the cost**. For example, somebody could host large video files, using your bucket for free storage and bandwidth.

Similarly, it is **not good security practice to grant permissions for *anyone* to list the contents of your bucket**. They might find sensitive data that was not intended to be released.

It would also be unwise to allow *anyone* to delete objects from your bucket, because somebody could delete *everything!*

There are two primary ways to grant access to objects:

**Bucket Policy**

A Bucket Policy can grant permissions on the whole bucket, or specific paths within a bucket. For example, granting `GetObject` to the whole bucket means that anyone can download any object.

See: [Bucket Policy Examples - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html)

**Object-level permissions**

Basic permissions can also be granted on a per-object basis. For example, when an object is copied to a bucket, the Access Control List (ACL) can specify who can access the object.

For example, this would grant ownership of the object to the bucket owner:

```
aws s3 cp foo.txt s3://my-bucket/foo.txt --acl bucket-owner-full-control
```

If the `--acl` is excluded, then the object 'belongs' to the identity that uploaded the file, which is why you were download your own file. This is not recommended, because it could lead to a situation where the bucket owner cannot access (and potentially cannot even delete!) the object.

**Bottom line:** Think about your security before implementing rules that grant other people, or anyone, permissions on your buckets.